# Is there any built-in SFTP with GUI on OSX?

Tags: macos, ssh, sftp

On my Ubuntu system, I can easily connect to a remote server via SFTP and simply drag/drop files across systems.  This is built into the standard file manager.

I just recently got a MBP with OSX and am looking to do the same thing. When I go to Finder->Go->Connect to Server, there is not SFTP option (but there is FTPS). It looks like I can't just use a regular Finder window to manage remote files via SFTP.

I know there are clients such as Cyberduck, Fugu, and FileZilla, but it seems like this should be built in.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [SSHFS](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/wiki/MACFUSE_FS_SSHFS) with [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) to connect to SFTP servers (SSHFS) natively, and they'll show up in the Finder as if it was an SMB or AFP mounted drive. This is (in my opinion) the easiest way to do it, and it's nice that it's not a separate program like CyberDuck, but integrated right into the Finder.

Comment: Nice, thanks! As you point out, I didn't want to use a separate program, but just use the finder.  I'll check out SSHFS/MacFUSE.